# How can we use Database name in SQLite Query, when database file is located in different location?

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

Application directory  - /var/www/

database file location - /home/user/sqlite/db_name

Using PDO for connection

SQL queries are executed successfully if database name is not used. Otherwise it throws error **table not found** due to different location and we cannot use the path in SQL queries.

How can we handle this if database name need to specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify database name in the query.

You have to specify it in the DSN, like this

```
$pdo = new PDO("sqlite:/home/user/sqlite/db_name");
```

To be able to specify database name in the query, you need a real DBMS, not a toy one. Mysql for example.

Comment: Yes for MySql or PostgreSql we can use. So you mean it is not possible for SQLite